# Run already running app in OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift2

I am running this code

```
let task = NSTask()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
        task.arguments = ["open -a Firefox"]        
        task.launch()
```

But getting error

> env: open -a Firefox: No such file or directory

Anybody knows whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It found the answer, Just need to slightly modify the code.

```
task.arguments = ["open", "-a", "Firefox"]
```